# Using the background color from BootStrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So i was just exprimenting when i realized that when i put a div with the class of btn, it also makes the div a btn but the interesting part is that it has a really nice background.
Is it possible for me to use that background? I really want to make it the background color of my sidebar.

Comment: search for the class `.btn` in your css file and see what background image it is using

Comment: why dont you inspect the CSS, get the properties that create it (most likely the gradients and filters) and put it on a class of your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [should really consider installing Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to inspect some elements on the page and their CSS properties (in this case).

Firebug will allow you to select an element and check all the related CSS to that element. Then you can search what property you liked, and just copy it into your own class in your CSS file.

[image: It will show you up an interface similar to this one]